# Tell C to inline function but still have it available to call debugger

Tags: c, gcc

Is there anyway to mark a function as inline, but still have at available to call at the debugger? All of my functions I would like to call are marked as `static inline`, because we are only allowed to expose certain functions in our file. I'm using gcc.

Comment: To have a function being local to its translation unit (.c file) it is sufficient to declare it as `static`. There is no need to inline it to "hide" it.

Comment: Do you do special debug builds?

Comment: @alk I do not do special debug bulids.

Comment: I'd start thinking about doing so (also see [Clifford's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52690706/694576) below).

Comment: `-fkeep-inline-functions  -fkeep-static-functions` maybe?

Comment: If you want to avoid exporting a function, it is sufficient to mark it `static`; there is no need to use `static inline`. Bu that won't guarantee that the compiler will actually generate the function as a callable entity.

Answer (score 1):

`-ginline-points` could help:

> Generate extended debug information for inlined functions. Location view tracking markers are inserted at inlined entry points, so that address and view numbers can be computed and output in debug information. This can be enabled independently of location views, in which case the view numbers won’t be output, but it can only be enabled along with statement frontiers, and it is only enabled by default if location views are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

In-lined functions have no return instruction, so even if you had the address of the start of the in-lined function, calling it from the debugger would execute the code that follows the in-lining, of which it would almost certainly not have a suitable stack frame.

It is not usual, and certainly not easy do debug optimised code in any case.  Normally one would simply switch optimisation off for debugging - in GCC at least, the `inline` keyword is ignored at `-O0`.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the issues when optimizing the code. You need to lower the optimizations a little bit (Usual recommendations in CMake for instance is to use -O2 instead of -O3) and add `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` to the command line (it will make code slower, as it allocates a register to keep track on the stack frame pointer during function calls).

On compilers like ICC, you can have even more debug info by using `-debug all`.